# Changing position of the table view when navigated between views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, ios5

I have a table view in one of my view, I scroll down to the bottom of the table and then if I load another view which also has table view, Table view is not changing its position.

For Example:- If i am scrolling my table to its bottom and from there if i navigate, the new view having table view shows me bottom of table.

Instead I need to show the top of the table.

Please suggest me,earlier it worked fine in< iOS 5.

Thank you
Narasimha

Comment: Could you maybe show code? The problem seems somewhat odd... An easy solution would be to just use the scrollToRowAtIndexPath method of the new view to manually scroll to the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When You push the view
In view will appear try

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 [self.tableview selectRowAtIndexPath:Nil animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
}
```

Hope this helps.